# What does "try and avoid"phrase mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Today I saw this "try and avoid" phrase in a sentence .  "Try and avoid repeating the problems with the images dataset". What does "try and avoid" in this sentence mean? Is it the same with "try to avoid ? "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Try and avoid](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=try%20and%20avoid%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctry%20and%20avoid%3B%2Cc0)*** :

is an informal constructions often used colloquially  The meaning of  *try and avoid* is *try to avoid.*

As suggested by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and)

> With certain verbs, "and" can mean "in order to":
>
> - I asked him to go and find my glasses.
> - Come and see me tomorrow.
> - Wait and see (= wait in order to see) what happens.
> - ***informal*** Try and get (= try to get) some tickets for tonight's performance.

and [Collind Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/and) on the usage of “try and” instead of “try to” states:

> - The use of and instead of to after try and wait is typical of spoken language, but should be avoided in any writing which is not informal: We must try to prevent (not try and prevent) this happening.

As noted in the language site  [Wordmall](http://verbmall.blogspot.com/2006/10/try-to-vs-try-and.html):

> Most grammarians will endorse the expression “try to avoid” , at least in formal writing or speechmaking. The tradition is that when the first verb is a command or a strong request
>   (the imperative mood), the verb that follows should be in the infinitive form (to + verb):
>
> - *Try to avoid excessive noise.
>     Come to see us when you get a chance.
>     Be sure to get an application form on the way out.*
>
> However, in informal use, the word and often replaces the word to:
>
> - *Try and avoid excessive noise.
>     Come and see us when you get a chance.
>     Be sure and get an application form on the way out.*